# Trigger click on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, iframe

I'm aware of the same-origin policy... just getting that out of the way.

Anyway, I have a slideshow (slide.js) that has some embedded videos in it. When the user clicks the video, I want the slideshow to pause. Events from inside the iframe do not trigger, so I'm trying to work around that. Right now I have a partial solution. I detect a `blur` event on `window` and if the newly focused element is an `iframe` then I pause the slideshow:

```
$(window).blur(function(event){
    console.log(event.target);
    if($('iframe').is(':focus')){
        //clicked inside iframe
        console.log('test');
    }
    console.log('document.activeElement is:');
    console.log(document.activeElement);
    console.log('\n');
});
```

After loading the page I get this in the console:

```
document.activeElement is:
BODY
```

Now the part that confuses me. The click event only fires the `iframe` focus event when I click *somewhere other than the `iframe` first*. That is, after loading the page, if I directly click the iframe, the console does not log test. If I click either outside the frame, or another tab in the browser, or anywhere else, the `blur` event will trigger. After that if I click the iframe, then I get test in the console:

After loading the page, I click a different tab then go back to original tab:

```
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
document.activeElement is: 
<body class="full">...</body>
```

Then I click the iframe:

```
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
test
document.activeElement is: 
<iframe>...</iframe>
```

Why???

I even put this before everything, and it didn't help:

```
$(window).focus();
```

However, it works if I do this:

```
$('input').focus();
```

If the input is focused, then I can click the iframe and trigger the event without having to click anything else beforehand.

Help me, you're my only hope...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Actually, just using the native `window.focus()` seems to work for me :

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFVgC/3/)

---

How about just appending another element to set the focus to :

```
$('<input>', {type: 'text', 
              style: 'top: -10000px; position: absolute', 
              autofocus:true}
    ).appendTo('body')
     .focus(); // just to make sure
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFVgC/1/)

If you can, I would add an input element with autofocus directly to the markup, that way the blur event is always triggered on the first click.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aFVgC/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There actually is an input already on the page, and I have tried this before and it works when I focus that first. Its possible other forms with autofocus could conflict with this, so this is a last resort solution.

Comment: Yes it does. I could have swore I tried that one already... interestingly enough, $(window).focus() does not work. I will accept your answer momentarily. First I would like someone to try and explain why this happened this way.

Comment: @jefffabiny - I also tried the jQuery version with no luck, but the native version seems to work for some reason. jQuery probably does some interal checking to avoid calling focus on what it believes to be non-focusable elements to avoid errors.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a workaround:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('body').prop('tabindex', -1).focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which video service you are using, it would be best to use their video API. Then you *can* get video events and know exactly when to pause and/or resume your slideshow.

- [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) ([demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo))

  ```
  <script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
  ```
- [Vimeo API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) (nice [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/HfwWY/light/) using Froogaloop)

  ```
  <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
  ```

Comment: This is a potential solution. We in fact use both those services and potentially more down the road. So this will work if I can't find something better. Regardless, I'm very curious why the browser is behaving this way.

Comment: I had to do this for [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.github.io/AnythingSlider/video.html) when I wrote the video extension.